# Concurrent collections is it safe to modify from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrent-collections

Let say I have:

```
MyCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
```

I now it is **safe to add and remove** items from `MyCollection` . But What about modifying items. For example is it safe to do:

```
MyCollection["key"] = 1;   // thread 1
```

and

```
MyCollection["key"] = 2;   // thread 2
```

---

### Example 2:

```
MyCollection2 = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

Is it safe to do?

```
MyCollection2["key"].Add(1);  // Thread1
```

and

```
MyCollection2["key"].Add(2);  // Thread2
```

where Thread1 and Thread2 are executing at the same time. Do I have to create a lock when modifying items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not it is safe to modify the item is entirely independent on whether or not it is in a `ConcurrentDictionary`.  That's no different than just having a list that you mutate from two different threads.  In the case of `List`, it's not safe; if you use a type that is *designed* to be mutated from multiple different threads, such as a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<int>>` then that would be fine.

`ConcurrentQueue` is *only* ensuring that calls to methods of that class are observed to be atomic; it is making no other guarantees surrounding thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

The first is perfectly safe.  The ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe, so getting/setting values on different threads at the same time won't cause issues.

Your second is not safe.  Just because a ConcurrentDictionary contains a reference to an instance of type X does not make type X thread safe.  Neither does it block while accessing the value of any particular key.

Remember,

```
MyCollection2["key"].Add(1);
```

is the same as

```
var list = MyCollection2["key"];
list.Add(1);
```

It is clear that, in this case, all thread-safe code (ConcurrentDictionary access) has completed, but non-thread safe code (`List<T>` access) has *not*.